# Splitting single column into four columns and count repeated pattern in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr

Aim of this project is understand how information is acquired while looking into an object. Imagine an object has elements like `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f`. A person might look at `a` and move onto to `b` and so forth. Now, we wish to plot and understand how that person have navigated across the different elements of a given stimuli. I have data that captured this movement in a single column but I need split this into few columns to get the navigation pattern. Please find the example given below.

I have column extracted from a data frame. Now it has to be split into four columns based on its characteristics.

```
a <- c( "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "d", "d", "d", "e", "f", "f", "e", "e", "f")
a <- as.data.frame(a)
```

Expected output

```
from   to   countfrom   countto

a      b      1           3
b      a      3           1
a      c      1           1
c      a      1           1
a      b      1           1
b      d      1           3
d      e      3           1      
e      f      1           2
f      e      2           2
e      f      2           1
```

Note: I used `dplyr` to extract from the dataframe.

Comment: `countfrom` is based on number of the times the `from` element has been repeated in the column. `countto` is number of times the `to` element is repeated in the column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `rle` to get the relative runs of each letter, and then piece it together:

```
r <- rle(a$a)
## or maybe `r <- rle(as.character(a$a)` depending on your R version
setNames(
    data.frame(lapply(r, head, -1), lapply(r, tail, -1)),
    c("countfrom","from","countto","to")
)
##   countfrom from countto to
##1          1    a       3  b
##2          3    b       1  a
##3          1    a       1  c
##4          1    c       1  a
##5          1    a       1  b
##6          1    b       3  d
##7          3    d       1  e
##8          1    e       2  f
##9          2    f       2  e
##10         2    e       1  f
```

Comment: is it also possible to add the grouping variable to this rle function?? Imagine the first few rows comes from participant A1 and the rest comes from participant A2. Will I be able to add this information to the output of `rle` function?

Answer (score 3):

Or in the tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- c( "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "d", 
        "d", "d", "e", "f", "f", "e", "e", "f")
foo <- rle(a)

answ <- tibble(from = foo$values, to = lead(foo$values),
               fromCount = foo$lengths, toCount = lead(foo$lengths)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(to))


# A tibble: 10 x 4
   from  to    fromCount toCount
   <chr> <chr>     <int>   <int>
 1 a     b             1       3
 2 b     a             3       1
 3 a     c             1       1
 4 c     a             1       1
 5 a     b             1       1
 6 b     d             1       3
 7 d     e             3       1
 8 e     f             1       2
 9 f     e             2       2
10 e     f             2       1
```

Comment: Your welcome.  I find `rle` and `lead` easier to get my head around than `lapply`.  Or, heaven help us, `reduce`.

Comment: That's true David. I really like simplicity. It is hard to accept both the answers in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it also possible to add the grouping variable to this rle function?? Imagine the first few rows comes from participant A1 and the rest comes from participant A2. Will I be able to add this information to the output of `rle` function? Especially, I would like to work with `dplyr` pipes.

Comment: I think so... but I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  I suggest you compose this as a separate question.  Supply a link back to this post for reference.  But supply a new table showing the result you're looking for.

Comment: Dear @David T, as recommend by you. I have posted the a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991055/using-rle-function-along-with-dplyr-group-by-command-to-mapping-grouping-v