# Using `rle` function along with `dplyr` `group_by` command to mapping grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with three columns that has information similar to the data frame given below. Now I wish to extract information search pattern based on the information in column `a`.

Based on the support from few developers (@thelatemail and @David T), I was able to identify the pattern with `rle` function, please see here - [using rle function to identify pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967678/splitting-single-column-into-four-columns-and-count-repeated-pattern-in-r). Now, I wish to move ahead and add grouping information to the extracted pattern. I tried with `dplyr` `do` function - refer to the code below. However, this does not work.

The example data and desired output is given as well for your reference.

```
##mycode that produces error - needs to be fixed
test <- data%>%
  group_by(b, c)%>%
  do(.,  data.frame(from = rle(.$a)$values), to = lead(rle(.$a)$values))
```

```
##code to create the data frame
a <- c( "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "d", "d", "d", "e", "f", "f", "e", "e")
b <- c(rep("experiment", times = 8), rep("control", times = 8))
c <- c(rep("A01", times = 4), rep("A02", times = 4), rep("A03", times = 4), rep("A04", times = 4))
data <- data.frame(c,b,a)
```

```
## desired output

    c      b         from  to    fromCount toCount
                    <chr> <chr>     <int>   <int>
 1 A01 experimental  a     b             1       3
 2 A02 experimental  a     c             1       1
 3 A02 experimental  c     a             1       1
 4 A02 experimental  a     b             1       1
 5 A03 control       d     e             3       1
 6 A04 control       f     e             2       2
```

Compared to the earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967678/splitting-single-column-into-four-columns-and-count-repeated-pattern-in-r), the information gets compressed since we apply grouping to the `a` column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(b, c, grp = rleid(a)) %>%
  summarise(from = first(a), fromCount = n()) %>% 
  mutate(to = lead(from), toCount = lead(fromCount)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(to)) %>%
  arrange(c)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#  b          c     from  fromCount to    toCount
#  <chr>      <chr> <chr>     <int> <chr>   <int>
#1 experiment A01   a             1 b           3
#2 experiment A02   a             1 c           1
#3 experiment A02   c             1 a           1
#4 experiment A02   a             1 b           1
#5 control    A03   d             3 e           1
#6 control    A04   f             2 e           2
```

---

Or using `rle`, after grouping by 'b', 'c', `summarise` with `rle` to create a `list` column, then extract the 'values' and 'lengths' from column in `summarise`, create the 'to', 'toCount' on the `lead` of the 'from', 'fromCount' column `filter` out the `NA` elements and `arrange` the rows based on the 'c' column

```
data %>% 
    group_by(b, c) %>%
    summarise(rl = list(rle(a)), 
              from = rl[[1]]$values, 
              fromCount = rl[[1]]$lengths) %>% 
    mutate(to = lead(from), 
           toCount = lead(fromCount)) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-rl) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(to)) %>% 
    arrange(c)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#  b          c     from  fromCount to    toCount
#  <chr>      <chr> <chr>     <int> <chr>   <int>
#1 experiment A01   a             1 b           3
#2 experiment A02   a             1 c           1
#3 experiment A02   c             1 a           1
#4 experiment A02   a             1 b           1
#5 control    A03   d             3 e           1
#6 control    A04   f             2 e           2
```

We could also loop over the `rle` `list` column ('rl') with `map`, extract the components, and take the `lead` of the `lengths`, `values` in a `tibble`, use `unnest_wider` to create the columns and `unnest` the `list` structure, `filter` out the NA elements and `arrange`

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
data %>% 
     group_by(b, c) %>%
     summarise(rl = list(rle(a))) %>%
     ungroup %>%
     mutate(out = map(rl, 
          ~ tibble(from = .x$values,
                   fromCount = .x$lengths,
                   to = lead(from), 
                   toCount = lead(fromCount)))) %>%
     unnest_wider(c(out)) %>% 
     unnest(from:toCount) %>%
     filter(!is.na(to)) %>% 
     arrange(c) %>% 
     select(-rl)
```

Comment: the first solution works well with the provided example. Whereas, the second solution with `rle` function throws an error - Error: Column `from` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2. Is it working at your end??

Comment: @BalachandarKaliappan yes, it is working fine for me.  Can you show your dplyr package version

Comment: my version is `dplyr_0.8.5`

Comment: I am using the devel version of dplyr

Comment: @BalachandarKaliappan I updated with a modified solution.  I hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks a lot Arun. The updated solution works well. Between, I am also updating installing the devel version of `dplyr`, will update you if that works as well.

Comment: @BalachandarKaliappan thanks, I understand why my solution didn't work and I am thinking that it could be a bug in the devel because `summarise` should only return a single row as output, but when we do the extraction with `$values`, `$lengths`, it simply expands the rows instead of throwing an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214540/discussion-between-balachandar-kaliappan-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2):

Or in the `tidyverse`, create a function that does the `rle` for the Tracking for a single subject

```
rleSlice <- function(Tracking) {

  rlTrack <- rle(as.character(Tracking))  # Strip the levels from the factor, they interfere
  tibble(from = rlTrack$values, to = lead(rlTrack$values),
                 fromCount = rlTrack$lengths, toCount = lead(rlTrack$lengths)) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(to)) %>% 
    list()
}
```

Make sure it's behaving

```
[[1]]
rleSlice(c("a", "b", "b", "b", "c"))

A tibble: 2 x 4
  from  to    fromCount toCount
  <chr> <chr>     <int>   <int>
1 a     b             1       3
2 b     c             3       1
```

Now we'll group and get the *rle* for each participant

```
data %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
    # This is easier to track than all these a,b,c's
  rename(Subject = c, Test = b, Tracking = a) %>% 
  group_by(Subject, Test) %>% 
  summarise(Slice = rleSlice(Tracking)) %>% 
  unnest(col = "Slice") %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Subject Test       from  to    fromCount toCount
  <fct>   <fct>      <chr> <chr>     <int>   <int>
1 A01     experiment a     b             1       3
2 A02     experiment a     c             1       1
3 A02     experiment c     a             1       1
4 A02     experiment a     b             1       1
5 A03     control    d     e             3       1
6 A04     control    f     e             2       2
```

Comment: Thanks @David T - this solution also works well. I appreciate your efforts in solving my questions.