# Is there an R function to extract repeating rows of numbers?

Tags: r, csv

I am looking to extract timepoints from a table.
Output should be the starting point in seconds from column 2 and the duration of the series. But output only if the stage lasts for at least 3 minutes ( if you look at the seconds column) so repetition of either stage 0,1,2,3 or 5 for more than 6 consecutive lines of the stage column.

So in this case the 0-series does not qualify, while the following 1-series does.
desired output would be : 150, 8
starting at timepoint 150 and lasting for 8 rows.

I was experimenting with `rle()`, but haven't been successful yet..

| Stage | Seconds |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 30 |
| 0 | 60 |
| 0 | 90 |
| 0 | 120 |
| 1 | 150 |
| 1 | 180 |
| 1 | 210 |
| 1 | 240 |
| 1 | 270 |
| 1 | 300 |
| 1 | 330 |
| 1 | 360 |
| 1 | 390 |
| 0 | 420 |

Comment: Hi @Slevin! You describe two seemingly different criteria for keeping a group: (1) "the stage lasts for at least 3 minutes" and (2) "repetition of [...] stage [...] for more than 6 lines". Are both true at the same time? In addition, since you mention `rle`, I assume _consecutive_ sequences of "stages" are important. Can you please try to clarify this in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Hey@Henrik! the two criteria are basically the same just looking at the two different columns as repetition for more than 6 lines is equal to a duration of 3 minutes.! And, yes of course consecutive sequences, fixed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how representative of your data this might be. This may be an option using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(grp = c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(stage))))) %>% 
  filter(stage == 1) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(count = n() - 1) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1, count >= 6) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(grp, stage))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   seconds count
#>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     960    16
#> 2    1500     7
#> 3    2040    17
#> 4    2670    10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**data**

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(stage = sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.8)),
                 seconds = seq(0, by = 30, length.out = 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61991105/12400385), you can use `data.table::rleid()` with `dplyr`

```r
df <- structure(list(Stage = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Seconds = c(0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 
                                                              150L, 180L, 210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 330L, 360L, 390L, 420L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                -15L))
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)


df %>%
  filter(Seconds > 0) %>%
  group_by(grp = rleid(Stage)) %>%
  filter(n() > 6)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   grp [1]
#>   Stage Seconds   grp
#>   <int>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     150     2
#> 2     1     180     2
#> 3     1     210     2
#> 4     1     240     2
#> 5     1     270     2
#> 6     1     300     2
#> 7     1     330     2
#> 8     1     360     2
#> 9     1     390     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>